# Irreversible compression

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, energy, work

> A vertical thermally insulated cylinder of volume $V$ contains $n$ moles of an ideal monoatomic gas under a weightless piston. A load of weight $W$ is placed on the piston as a result of which the piston is displaced by a distance $h$. Determine the final temperature of the gas. Take area of cross section as $A$ and atmospheric pressure $P0$.

My approach:I conserved the total number of moles before and after attaing final equilibrium.I also applied the Work Energy theorem on the piston:Work done by(gas+atmosphere+gravity)=0. So I'm getting the work done by gas as -(P0*A*h+Mgh) which is equal to the negative of the change in internal energy of the gas. However the author gives the equation:Mgh=change in internal energy of gas. Why has he skipped the work done by the atmosphere. Can I prove mathematically that only the work done by gravity goes into change in internal energy of gas?Is it because the system was initially in equilibrium under atmospheric pressure?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why doesn't the work done by atmosphere contribute to increase in internal energy of gas?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/546570/)

Comment: You have asked the same question here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/546570/. Also what Chet Miller has written there is correct. Work done by atmosphere must be included. Your system is only the gas inside the cylinder in this case. So using 1st law of thermodynamics, $dQ=0=dU+W_{by gas} = dU-W_{ext=gravity+atmosphere}=dU-(Mgh+PoAh)$. Why are you reluctant to accept that your book can be incorrect?

Comment: No,my professor also said that what the author has done is right..but he didn't explain me why.In the question you have provided, the user has failed to prove why the author is right

Comment: The Book i'm referring to is SS Krotov,from which questions have been asked in International Physics Olympiads and it has been reviewed many times by experts. There is no way it is incorrect. Also ,i have  already looked up for the solution to this question on the internet and it has been solved many times in the same way as the author has described

Comment: As I said when I addressed virtually the same question the last time I saw it, the work done by the atmosphere must be included.  So you are correct, and the author and (sadly) your professor are incorrect.

Comment: @Dylan Rodrigues Why don't you ask your professor for the reason and share what he tells with us?

Comment: Im assuming process to be quasi static:
Considering  chamber 1 to be atmosphere : dQ(1)=dU(1)+dW(1).
For gas chamber dQ(2)=dU(2)+dW
(2)
now,dQ1=dQ2=0 as there is no heat exchange.
Adding the two equations:
dU1+dU2+dW1+dW2=0;
dU1=0 as atmosphere will have negligible change in temperature (as it is huge)
Therefore,dU2-(P0A+mg)dx +P0Adx=0 
Therfore dU2=mgdx
Now we will put dU2=nCvdT and integrate both sides
So change in internal energy=work done by gravity!.is this the right way to prove assuming process to be quasi static

Comment: @Dylan Rodrigues You are over complicating things. There is no need to consider the surroundings+gas as our system. Also in your solution you have assumed atmosphere "inside" the gas chamber, thereby cancelling the effect of atmosphere everywhere. This isn't mentioned in the Question. However with that assumption, your solution is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Initial pressure of ideal gas, $P1=\text{atmospheric pressure}=P_o$,

Initial volume, $V_1=V$

Final pressure, $P2=P_o+\frac{W}{A}$ & final volume $V_2=V-Ah$

Use ideal gas equation to find the final temperature $T_2$ 
$$P_2V_2=n\bar{R}T_2$$ 
$$T_2=\frac{P_2V_2}{n\bar{R}}$$
Where $\bar{R}$ is universal gas constant

Comment: Find out the mistake in my equation and correct it please

Comment: Your  question is to find out the final temperature $T_2$? I gave a different approach to solve

Comment: Actually, the answer given does not have h in it. So they have eliminated h by using the equation work done=change in internal energy

Comment: But work done also includes $Mgh$ also include $h$. Isn't it? So your answer must have $h$

Comment: What you have done is also right, but h can be eliminated by writing the third equation.You have written only two equations. The author has given the answer without h in it so to match the answer,i want to eliminate h